# xsl format date (substring + concatenate ?)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I have the input

```
<Date value="20091223"/>
```

and I want the output to be

```
<Date>23122009</Date>
```

I was trying to use substring function to reformat the date

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Date,1,4)"/>
```

But how to concatenate the extracted year and months and day together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming whitespace isn't preserved, just put them one after the other:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Date,7,2)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Date,5,2)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Date,1,4)"/>
```

If whitespace is preserved, just put them all on the line, without spaces between them.

The Xpath [concatenation](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function%5Fconcat.html) function will also work, but I find it less readable:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($Date,7,2), substring($Date,5,2), substring($Date,1,4))"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(Date/@value, 7, 2)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(Date/@value, 5, 2)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(Date/@value, 1, 4)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the XSLT [concat function](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_concat.html). In your case it would be something like this (untested):

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($Date,1,4), substring($Date,7,2), substring($Date,5,2))"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($Date,7,2),substring($Date,5,2),substring($Date,1,4))"/>
```